# pylint error runs fine in python3.2 but fails in python3.3

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pylint

Running Ubuntu QQ:

I have a Python project that uses PyQt. In several places I import QtCore and QtGui:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

Until now, I have been using python3.2.x (3?)

When I run **pylint** against such files it reports an error:

```
"Line 1 E: No name 'QtCore' in module 'PyQt4'
```

***But the application runs fine anyhow.***

Now I installed Python 3.3 (on same path: .. /usr/bin/ ) and configured my project to use python3.3  and python fails:

```
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name QtCore
File "/myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

**What is going on? With python3.2, pylint reports error, Python has no problem with it, but with python3.3 it fails, with the error pylint reported in python3.2?**

Comment: Do you have PyQt4 installed in Python3.3?

Comment: @SethCurry - please explain - have upgradde python several times, never had to change anything. You're saying I have to reinstall PyQt because I'm running a new Python interpreter? It's located in the same place as the old one.

Comment: Some modules aren't compatible across versions of Python, much like most modules have different versions for Python 3.x and Python 2.x, some modules aren't compatible across multiple subversions (like PyCrypto.  There is a Python 2.6 version, and a Python 2.7 version, and the 2.7 version will not work in 2.6). I looked, and it appears people are using Python 3.3 with PyQt4, what version of PyQt4 do you have?

Comment: Well maybe - funny that pylint reported the error in 3.2 but it worked fine anyhow. I'm probably going to stick with 3.2 meanwhile - 3.3.1 isn't even in any repository yet AFAIK. IMO this is starting to become a bit of an issue with Python - still some big packages haven't moved to 3 and now in 3 were seeing fairly frequent new releases. Compromises the platform a bit...

Comment: There's still quite a bit of diehard support for 2.7, I personally tend to develop in 2.7, mainly because that's where Debian is heading, and I'm not sure of CentOS and RHEL, but I don't see them jumping into Python3 yet. There's also the issue that a large number of non-standard libraries have yet to be ported to Python 3.  There's also the fact that 2.7 has extended life support, so you can develop for it and not worry about updating to the next version for the next couple years.  And then there are those that oppose the design approach to Python 3, but there aren't many of those.

Comment: I heard that the new Ubuntu release comes with Python 3.3.1..?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I don't use Ubuntu myself.  Ubuntu is only one distro though, and their goal is to be the bleeding edge, so if you develop for Ubuntu, you should be prepared for frequent patching. Python 2.7 is becoming the mainline version, CentOS is still using Python 2.6 as their default, I assume RHEL is as well.  There's somewhat of a belief that those are your target distro's for anything "serious" (which I use not as a derogatory term, but rather as a reference to the difference between a media sorting application, and a remote system stat gathering program for example)

Comment: @SethCurry - not doing anything 'serious', just hacking around for myself, and I'm a Linux newbee-only been messing with it for about a year, at home, where it is my main platform, not at work. I'm getting the hang of it after 15 years of heavy duty Win 32 development. Ubuntu is the most accessible for newbees coming from Windows-not going to switch now, when still getting acclimated. If I ever have to work with a different distro, hopefully it will be in an environment where I won't have to worry about Linux management etc - that's for sysadmins and I'm a programmer by trade.

Comment: To be honest, 99% of what you learn in Ubuntu still applies everywhere else, there are just slight differences in things like file locations and such.  The only thing that really really changes on the surface level is package management, and Ubuntu uses a different service method I believe, the systemd one?  Other than that, everything else works.

Comment: The other major difference is that the other distro's don't "coddle" you as much, again, not derogatory, but the true Linux style is command line, and Ubuntu does a pretty good job of preventing you ever needing the command line, whereas everyone else expects that if you want to do any kind of system alteration, you open a command prompt.  For example, package management is almost exclusively CLI in most other distro's, Arch Linux doesn't even have a GUI for partitioning on install, they just dump you in an fdisk prompt and tell you to have fun, hehe

Comment: @SethCurry - I use terminal sessions a lot in Ubuntu - don't care for the GUI all that much, and I go back to the pre-windows days so a command prompt is not something I am afraid of - it's quicker when you know how. fdisk prompt? Been there, done that - about 25 years ago. :-) But of course Linux shells are much deeper and more complex than anything in msDos - that is where I am putting most of my emphasis - learning about the file structure, shell commands, etc. But since I'm a Linux newbee I fall back on the Ubuntu GUI a lot - it's not bad at all, but frankly, Win7 blows it away.

Comment: Linux has never really had a strength in appearances, Windows (almost) always looks better because that's one of their selling points.  It's shiny and looks cool, not that there aren't other benefits, but Aero desktop?  That was purely for looks.  Linux's strength is in the kernel underneath, it may not look pretty, and indeed, I have several computers which have no GUI on them because they're home file servers and such so they don't need them.  The Linux shell is truly amazing once you get the hang of it, but the learning curve is pretty steep which drives people away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error" pylint reports on PyQT import is because since PyQT has some C++ or some C in it, pylint cannot easily and automatically introspect the PyQt module and determine if your code correctly imports bits of that 3rd party module.

To solve that, there is an plugin project to pylint called [pylint-brains](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint-brain) into which one can specify ways of introspecting specific modules (or faking their introspection). It would be nice to have a contribution that would remove the "E" of this pretty common import.

For the ImportError, as discussed in the comments, I believe either you have to re-install PyQt for this version of python or PyQt is not yet compatible with 3.3, or something in your pythonpath is wrong.

Comment: The pylint error doesn't really bother me considering your explanation. I thought perhaps it was related to the failure I am seeing with Python 3.3, which was reporting the same thing as pylint, but it seems that is not the case. As for reinstalling PyQt, have done that - apt-get says there's nothing to do, I've already got the latest and greatest. This needs more investigation... Meanwhile Python 3.3 is not found in any of the regular ppa's, only 'experimental', so I will stick with 3.2.3 meanwhile. Perhaps this will sort itself out later... not a burning issue for me.